# View animation frame change

Tags: iphone, ios, animation, view, uiactionsheet

Are emerging in the   subview    scrolling animation. However    actionsheet    place when you scroll subview, not again appear in the first place.

```
 if(checkboxState == 0)
{
    NSTimeInterval animationDuration = 0.8;
    CGRect newFrameSize = CGRectMake(0, 155,320,120);
    [UIView beginAnimations:nil context:NULL];
    [UIView setAnimationDuration:animationDuration];
    subview.frame = newFrameSize;
    [UIView commitAnimations];
}
else if(checkboxState == 1)
{
    NSTimeInterval animationDuration = 0.8;
    CGRect newFrameSize = CGRectMake(0, 105,320,120);
    [UIView beginAnimations:nil context:NULL];
    [UIView setAnimationDuration:animationDuration];
    subview.frame = newFrameSize;
    [UIView commitAnimations];
  }
```

Pressing the View is a checkbox in the above code is provided to move up and down. However, even though actionsheet slipped up again when the first view is in place.

View is scrolled up, how can we keep it that way, even if opened actionsheet?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed the problem by using the
`subview.bounds`
Thank you for your helps.

Answer (score 0):

Use `[UIView setAnimationBeginsFromCurrentState:YES];` after both "beginAnimation".

Then the previous changes will be saved.

Comment: Hi Anc, The next section of code you specified is added beginAnimations line now, but still not much has changed. Again, returning to the first view subview